# How to add this to your discord bot command line

Tags: python, discord

I created a discord bot and I want a host command for game link and also want to let the message send in a different channel and that the channel command is toggeable.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def host(ctx):
    message = discord.Embed(title=f"Hosted by {ctx.author} \n Earnable points: [SOLOPOINTS] \n Link: {link} ")
    await ctx.send (embed=message)
```

But I don't know how to do the link feature, I want it to be like this "!host LINK.COM"

Comment: What should this link be to?

Comment: The link can be anything In general I want that people can do !host random link and that the link in the embed get changed rn posted in toggeable channel command